# Infragistics: UltraDropDown in UltraGrid disable editing text (UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.DropDownList)

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I would like the Cells in my UltraGrid (1 Column) to not have the text field editable when bound to a UltraDropDown

I believe I am having a similar issue to the person in this thread:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/3440/18306.aspx

My problem is that even though I set the UltraDropDown's Column style and the UltraGrid's Column style to `UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.DropDownList` they are still editable before and after selecting somthing from the list. I think this may be caused because not every row has a UltraDropDown List bound. This is because some rows need to be editiable by the user.

I have a UltraComboEditor on another part of the page working the way I would like the ultraDropDown's to work in the grid by using

```
UltraComboEditor1.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDownList
```

I can post some code if it helps, but just figured I'd ask if this is a known bug.

I also posted this on the Infragistics Forums: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/83456/416961.aspx#416961

Looks Like

[image]

Should Look like

[image]

Comment: there should be a data bind event, where you can disable your column

Comment: The thing is I don't want the column "Disabled", just want it so that they cannot enter text. if I disable it they cannot use the UltraDropDown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/83456/417008.aspx#417008) helped me out and resulted in me only setting the style for the rows that had a drop down.

```
parameterName = UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands("Bottom").AddNew()
parameterName.Cells("List").Value = array1(7, j)

 If Not parameterName.Cells("List").Value = "" Then
    parameterName.Cells("Values").ValueList = allDrop
    parameterName.Cells("Values").Value = array1(8, j)
    parameterName.Cells("Values").Style = UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.DropDownList
 Else
    parameterName.Cells("Values").Value = parameterName.Cells("HiddenVal").Value 'set for textbox
    parameterName.Cells("Values").Style = UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.Edit
 End If
```